# Changing x-axis tick colour in a ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm trying to change the colour of the X.axis tick colour to Black, as described here:
https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Axis-Attributes#axistextx-text
However when I run my code I'm getting the error message:
`Error: could not find function "theme"`

```
ggplot(long.repmixed.df, aes(x = log10intensity, colour = channel, fill = channel)) +
geom_bar(position="dodge") +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black")) +
opts(panel.background = theme_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 'black')) +
opts(panel.grid.major = none, panel.grid.minor = none)
```

I'm basically trying to plot a histogram with no grid and white BG. Can anybody rectify the problem please.

Comment: `opts()` is no longer in use for newer versions of `ggplot2`. The `theme()` function is what you should be using in versions newer than 0.9.1.

Comment: It looks like you can either update your version of `ggplots` or use the 'old' way of changing the text color. `opts(axis.text.x = theme_text(colour="black"), axis.text.y = theme_text(colour="black"))`

Comment: @MarkNielsen , post as answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you can either update your version of `ggplots` or use the 'old' way of changing the text color. `opts(axis.text.x = theme_text(colour="black"), axis.text.y = theme_text(colour="black"))`

The correct syntax should be `theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour="black"), axis.text.y = element_text(colour="black"))`.