# GGPLOT letter color

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to change the color of the letters same as of Bars.
I am using this code

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=reorder(Genotype,-Phy), y=Phy, fill=Specie, colour=Specie)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), color="black") + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Phy, ymax=Phy+sd), width=0.5,position=position_dodge(0.9)) + 
  geom_text(aes(y = Phy+sd+0.02, label = tk), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
            vjust=0.3,hjust=0.5, size = 3.5, angle=90) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(colour = "black",fill = "white"),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.5, linetype = 'solid',colour = "lightgray"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1, colour = "black", face = "bold"),
        axis.text.y =element_text(colour="black", size = "10", face = "bold"),
        legend.position=c(0.915, 0.85),legend.background = element_rect(fill='transparent'),
        legend.key.size = unit(4, 'mm'),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 9, face="italic", colour = "black")) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('#e9002d', '#ffaa00', '#00b000'))+ expand_limits(y=0.68)+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.1)) + labs(title="",y=y, x="")
```

and getting this graph
[image]

Comment: Please change this to a reproducible example so we can modify your code and provide an answer. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. For starters you want to supply data (it doesn't need to be your data just enough to reproduce this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might this approach help? I'm assuming by "letters" you mean variable `tk`?

In the absence of reproducible data I've knocked up a representative dataframe and only included ggplot arguments that address the question. You can adapt the code to suit your usecase.

Updated to include error bars with the colour by species.

```r
library(ggplot2)



df1 <- data.frame(species = c("s.ch", "s.co", "s.tu"),
                  genotype = c("BGB451", "BGB460", "BGB093"),
                  phy = c(0.52, 0.35, 0.29),
                  tk = c("a", "bcfg", "cfhij"),
                  sd = c(0.02, 0.06, 0.08))

ggplot(df1, aes(reorder(genotype, -phy), phy, fill = species))+
  geom_col() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = phy, 
                    ymax = phy + sd,
                    colour = species), width = 0.5) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = tk, colour = species),
            size = 10,
            nudge_y = 0.05, 
            angle = 90) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('#e9002d', '#ffaa00', '#00b000')) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c('#e9002d', '#ffaa00', '#00b000'))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I also want to add the error line over the bar with the same color. It is not working with my code.

Comment: Ah, I don't think this was stated in the question. Let me have a look at this.

Comment: See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

So you **can** specify colors as a vector to element_text (see [here for a non-vectorized example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706034/changing-x-axis-tick-colour-in-a-ggplot)), but it is not supported and may change.

```
Name <- c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria", "Ben", "Tina")
Age <- c(23, 41, 32, 58, 26)
df <- data.frame(Name, Age)

ggplot(df) + geom_col(aes(x = Name, y = Age, fill = Name)) + 
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour=c("black", "red", "blue", "green", "orange")))
```

Produces:

[image: toy example]

How you generate that vector is up to you. I didn't bother adapting it to your code but you can follow this to do that yourself. Remember that ggplot warns you this isn't supported and may change in the future, so you shouldn't rely on this being available in future versions or being correct now.